# Android/Boost.log application crashes at startup

Tags: android, boost, qt-creator

I am trying to integrate Boost.Log in a QT/QML project that has to work on Windows, Linux and Android. While Win32 and Linux versions work like a charm, Android is giving me a few headaches.

I was able to build Boost library following instructions at https://github.com/moritz-wundke/Boost-for-Android.

However,

- If I link my application statically to boost libraries, I get a bunch of linker errors, complaining that symbols are not found. Error messages are like: *"error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::get()'*, I get ~60 of them and I checked many times the file paths
- If I link dynamically to boost, I can successfully generate my APK (the relevant .so files are included) but it crashes upon startup, both on a real device and on Android emulator

I'm new to Android development so it's entirely possible that I'm missing some key step here and I'm not really sure on what information may be relevant to provide here. Hope that someone can help.

I tried building with both ndk 20 and 21, Boost 1.70, Android SDK 26.
I plan to use QT 5.12 but did not add any QT code yet. I used QT Creator 4.10.2 (Windows) and 4.11.1 (Linux)

Comment: Regarding linking errors, you should check that you don't define `BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` or `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` when you're linking statically. Regarding crashes, at least a backtrace would be useful.

Comment: I realize that - basically, I don't know how to take a backtrace on an Android device, can you point me to some relevant documentation on this? Thanks for the DYN_LINK tip btw, I'm trying that right now

Comment: BTW I was able to solve some of the linker error removing the BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK as you pointed out; I still have linker errors on the filesystem library, although I added the boost_system which is a dependency.

Comment: I don't know anything about debugging Android applications. Maybe you could use a remote debugger with QtCreator and Android emulator. Regarding filesystem linking errors, it is a different library from boost_system. You have to link both, and you have to specify them in the correct order in the linker command line.